# sequence does not exist exception using eclipseLink with oracle db

Tags: oracle, jpa, sequence, eclipselink

I've got the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
@SequenceGenerator(schema = "myschema", name = "seqGenerator", 
                   sequenceName  = "person_s1", allocationSize = 1)
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
```

the following exceptions are thrown:

```
Call: DROP SEQUENCE myschema.person_s1
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="DROP SEQUENCE myschema.person_s1")
[EL Warning]: 2010-11-01 17:21:51.051--ServerSession(10605044)--Exception [EclipseLink-    4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Error Code: 2289
Call: SELECT myschema.person_s1.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="SELECT myschema.person_s1.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL")
```

The sequence is genrated by EclipseLink and the query:

```
SELECT myschema.person_s1.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
```

works fine when used directly...

Any help appreciated

Regards Marcel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the following exceptions are thrown (...)

These traces are generated during schema creation when a particular database object doesn't exist and thus can't be dropped. EclipseLink report such cases as **`Warning`** (which are not `Error`), they can be ignored (you get your sequence, right?).

PS: Why do you use an allocation size of 1, don't you want to benefit from the high/low optimization?

Comment: Merci beaucoup Pascal. What is high/ low optimization? Might you drop me a line on that? Marcel

Comment: FWIW I've logged it as a bug in EclipseLink: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487795. Motivation for calling it a bug is in the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is going to sound really silly, but here it is anyway.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "myschema")
public class Person {

   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(schema = "myschema", name = "seqGenerator", sequenceName  = "person_s1", allocationSize = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "seqGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
}
```